# CUDA: Accessing arbitrary long matrices in both dimensions

Tags: matrix, cuda, rows

Hey there,
currently I'm using threads indexed only in one dimension to access all elements of a matrix like that:

```
// Thread-ID
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
// Offset:
int offset = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

while(idx < MATRIX_ROWS * MATRIX_COLS)
{   
    row = idx % MATRIX_ROWS;
    col = idx / MATRIX_ROWS;    

    matrix[ row ][ col ] = ...;
    idx += offset;
}
```

Now I wondered how to access arbitrary long matrices with two dimensional indexing. I would like that one block always access the single elements of one row. Something like that (x-index is refering to the cols and the y-index to the rows of the matrix):

```
// Thread-IDs
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

// Offset:
int offset = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

while(idx < MATRIX_COLS)
{   
    matrix[ idy ][ idx ] = ...;
    idx += offset;
}
```

Now let's assume the matrix has more rows than I started blocks when calling the kernel: When starting N blocks, the first N rows of the matrix are handled right, but what about the other rows? How would you do that?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: I came up with an idea but I don't know if that's somehow 'ugly' coding!?

```
// Thread-IDs
int idx0 = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int idx = idx0;
int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

// Offset:
int offsetx = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
int offsety = gridDim.y * blockDim.y;

while(idx < MATRIX_COLS && idy < MATRIX_ROWS)
{   
    matrix[ idy ][ idx ] = ...;

    idx += offsetx;
    if(idx > MATRIX_COLS)
    {
        // Jump to nex row and start from 'beginning' concerning columns
        idy += offsety;
        idx = idx0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this is what you are looking for?

```
// Thread-IDs
int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

// Offset:
int offsetx = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
int offsety = gridDim.y * blockDim.y;

for(row = idy; row < MATRIX_ROWS; i+=offsety) {
    float * pos = matrix + row;

#pragma unroll
    for(col = idx; col < MATRIX_COLS; col+=offsetx) {
        pos[col] = .....;
    }
}
```

If `MATRIX_COLS` is a preprocessor define or constant, the compiler might be able to unroll the inner loop and give a bit more performance.

EDIT: The first version of the code was written with column-major ordering stuck in the back of my head, so ignore the comment that was here. Access should be coalesced doing it this way.

Comment: OKay thanks, that looks pretty nice because there's no need for another variable idx0. Just a question: The version out of my edit would theoretically work too, right? Just that yours is a bit cleaner :)